# Can index can be used on and clause in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, relational-database

1. can index can be used on and clause in postgresql?
2. I am really confused when should i map one to many or many to many mapping in tables relations? please suggest anything or article.
3. is there is a ideal practice that n:n relation should be mapped with a mapping table 1:n with primary key and foreign key.

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

1. Of course an index can be used with `AND`. Two examples:

   ```
   test=> EXPLAIN (COSTS OFF) SELECT attname FROM pg_attribute
          WHERE attrelid = 'pg_class'::regclass AND attnum = 1;
                               QUERY PLAN
   ------------------------------------------------------------------
    Index Scan using pg_attribute_relid_attnum_index on pg_attribute
      Index Cond: ((attrelid = '1259'::oid) AND (attnum = 1))
   (2 rows)
   ```

   This uses a multicolumn index for both conditions at once.

   ```
   test=> EXPLAIN (COSTS OFF) SELECT attname FROM pg_attribute
          WHERE attrelid = 'pg_class'::regclass AND attlen = 64;
                            QUERY PLAN
   ------------------------------------------------------------
    Bitmap Heap Scan on pg_attribute
      Recheck Cond: (attrelid = '1259'::oid)
      Filter: (attlen = 64)
      ->  Bitmap Index Scan on pg_attribute_relid_attnum_index
            Index Cond: (attrelid = '1259'::oid)
   (5 rows)
   ```

   Here an index can be used for the first condition, while there is no index for the second condition – it is used as *filter* for the index scan.

   PostgreSQL can also use indexes for `AND` conditions where each individual condition can use a different index; this is done with *Bitmap Index Scan*s on both conditions that are combined with a *BitmapAnd*.
   This is usually less performant than a multicolumn index, but can be the way to go for large analytical queries.
2. and 3. *Many-to-many relationships* (also called *m:n relationships*) will always be modeled with a mapping table.  The primary key of the mapping table is usually the combination of the primary keys of both tables, see this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29).

   *One-to-many relationships* (also called *1:n relationships*) are always implemented with a foreign key from the 'many' side to the 'one' side.